# Regex to find everything in sentence containing word

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how to find the sentence containing a certain word so lets say the word is 'wow' then in the three following strings

`\nOkay hold on. This is pretty wow in here. Okay.\n`

`\nThis is super wow. Doesn't get much more wow than that.\n`

`\nHold up. wow.\n`

`\nOkay wow. Just wow!\n`

would yield the following respectively:

`This is pretty wow in here`

`This is super wow.`

`wow.`

`Okay wow.`

I am doing this in Python3 so I have the luxury of writing if statements but it is messy and I am hoping to avoid doing so. Here is my code for what **was** working but started failing. Maybe I am just too bad at Regex and am over complicating this.

```
    m = re.search('(?:(\.\s[A-Z]))(?=(.*)' + name+ '([^a-z^A-Z]))([^.]*)(\.\s[A-Z])', node.getIntroText())
    if m == None:
        m = re.search('(?:(\.\s[A-Z]))(?=(.*)' + name+ '([^a-z^A-Z]))(.*)(\.\s[A-Z])', node.getIntroText())
    if m == None:
        m = re.search('(?:([\r\n]))(?=(.*)' + name+ '([^a-z^A-Z]))([^.]*)(\.\s[A-Z])', node.getIntroText())
```

Essentially I want to capture the (first period or newline) instance before 'name' all the way to the next instance of a period followed by a (space and anything but a letter) or a new line.

Comment: Use NLTK to parse a paragraph into sentences, then just use `filter()` with `re.compile(r'\bwow\b').search`, or there are even ways to do it without regex then.

Comment: @anubhava fails for this test: '\nLogic wow. Holy.\n'

Comment: @anubhava because I am looking for the first match. It can be in the output if it makes it easier then i can just catch the first instance in python.

Comment: ok check this demo: https://regex101.com/r/jQVnPP/4

Comment: @anubhava fails on "Well. Wow."

Comment: That is `Wow` with capital `W` and you never mentioned that you wanted ignore case match. In any case it is just matter of using ignore case matching by using `re.I` or `(?i)` at the start of regex

Answer (score 1):

Converting my comment to answer. You may use this regex

```
>>> reg = re.compile(r"^(?:(?:(?!\bwow\b)[^.\n])*\. +)*((?:[a-z][^.\n]*?)?\bwow\b[^.\n]*)(?=\.)", re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
>>> test_str = ("\n"
...     "Okay hold on. This is pretty wow in here. Okay.\n\n"
...     "This is super wow. Doesn't get much more wow than that.\n\n"
...     "Hold up. wow.\n\n"
...     "Okay wow. Just Wow!\n")
>>> print ( reg.findall(test_str) )
```

```
['This is pretty wow in here', 'This is super wow', 'wow', 'Okay wow']
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jQVnPP/6)

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:(?:(?!\bwow\b)[^.\n])*\. +)*`: Match 0 or more sentences that don't contain `wow`.
- `((?:[a-z][^.\n]*?)?\bwow\b[^.\n]*)`: Match a sentence containing word `wow`
- `(?=\.)`: Assert that we have dot at next position
- Modes `re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE` are for multiline and ignore-case

Answer (score 1):

Calling `re.replace()` makes life simple:

```
wowSentence = re.sub('.*?(?:^|\. *)([^.]*\bwow\b[^.]*).*', '$1', paragraph)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/mv8ohYvfAT).

Add `(?i)` to the front of the regex to match `wow` case insensitively.